# How Do I Structure This JSON CloudFormation Template

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

From this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/managing-lambdaedge-and-cloudfront-deployments-by-using-a-ci-cd-pipeline/), it shows how to deploy a `AWS::Serverless::Function` as a 'proxy' to do routing, a/b testing, etc.

The example template is in YAML, but we need to use JSON as that is what the AWS dotnet templates are built on.

There is a line in the YAML that I cannot figure out how to translate to a JSON template:

`LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref LambdaEdgeFunctionSample.Version`

In a JSON template a `Ref` just refers to another resource or parameter.  You cannot `Ref` to a `Resource.Property`.  For that you use `Fn::GetAtt`.

I have tried `Fn::GetAtt`, but that errors with "Version is an unknown attribute for this resource" (in the editor) and `Template error: every Fn::GetAtt object requires two non-empty parameters, the resource name and the resource attribute` during deployment:

`"LambdaFunctionARN":{"Fn::GetAtt":["LambdaEdgeFunctionSample","Version"]}}`

Mind you, these are both using AWS::Serverless::Function underneath, so there's more transforming going on.

Specifically, when the JSON template is transformed, it does create:

```
"LambdaEdgeFunctionSampleVersion1cfc342538": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Version",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
      "Properties": {
        "FunctionName": {
          "Ref": "LambdaEdgeFunctionSample"
        }
      }
    },
```

But I cannot use `LambdaEdgeFunctionSampleVersion1cfc342538` as clearly that is a transient id.

How can I accomplish the same as the YAML template in a JSON template?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, AWS SAM does a transformation on `!Ref LambdaEdgeFunctionSample.Version` before the template is actually processed.

So, in Json, it's the same and SAM does the transformation:

`{"Ref":"LambdaEdgeFunctionSample.Version"}`

transforms to

```
{
  "Ref": "LambdaEdgeFunctionSampleVersionf76b18e3ba"
}
```